# Workaround for Vista BSOD when setting SATA drive frm AHCI to standard when trying to setup Dual Boot w/XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, multi-boot, ahci

I was trying to setup a friends laptop to dual boot vista/xp like mine. However after some searching, I found that his BIOS has his SATA setup to use AHCI mode. If I change that back to legacy or normal, which ever it was, Vista will BSOD on us. My question is if I run the repair function from Vista, do you think this will resolve the BSOD Vista gets when trying to run from the non-AHCI enabled SATA? Or am I stuck with having to make a slip-streamed XP install and try to get the AHCI drivers on the disk for XP?

THanks for your help.

John K.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Microsoft [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976) that references what you need to do to turn on AHCI, so it is theoretically possible that you could change the value back from 0 to what it was before (I believe the value is 3, but that is from inspecting drivers in the registry, not from actual experience), thereby disabling the AHCI driver and possibly allowing it to boot in IDE emulation mode. This is all theory and your mileage may vary, however, and the effort needed to recover from failure might be better spent just slipstreaming AHCI support into your XP install media.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to slipstream xp, just plug in a usb floppy and use the F6 prompt to add the SATA drivers when your installing XP.  If you do want to do an integrated CD I'd really recommend nlite since this turns the whole process into a matter of ticking boxes allowing you to slipstream in service packs and add drivers really easily.